# import error on transformers and tenserflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.bert.modeling_tf_bert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_load_context_function'
```

```
sentiment_analysis = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model="ProsusAI/finbert")
@app.route('/news', methods=['POST'])
def analyze_news_sentiment():
    data = request.json
    news_text = data.get('news_text')

    # Perform sentiment analysis
    result = sentiment_analysis(news_text)

    return jsonify(sentiment=result[0]['label'])
```

how to solve this error

Answer (score -1):

Seems a version compatibility problem.

I would try to pin version of python to 3.10 and tensorflow/keras seeking stability.

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.10
conda activate my_env
python -m pip install tensorflow==2.15.0 keras==2.15.0
```

And try to run your program with this setup

Comment: for `python -m pip install tensorflow==2.15.0 keras==3.5.0` it gives me python -m pip install keras==3.5.0          
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras==3.5.0 (from versions: 0.2.0,..2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0rc0, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0rc3, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc2, 2.7.0, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras==3.5.0

Comment: I would try version keras==2.15.0 then. Updating response also :)